# When I import jdl files just client-side is generated

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I'm working with jhipster and for some reason when I perform jhipster import-jdl db/jhipster-jdl.jh or jhipster:entity someEntity jhipster just generate the client-side, any java file is generated.

I also figured out that any file related to liquibase was generated for the entity that I want create

I tried to create the liquibase files manualy, and I got the database updated, but any java file was generated.

Do you have any idea?

My .yo-rc.json is:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.devs2go",
      "nativeLanguage": "es"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.13.1",
    "baseName": "Agenda",
    "packageName": "com.devs2go",
    "packageFolder": "com/devs2go",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "54a29352e3a49129d3874f5ec2802fe57e9a99f6",
    "clientFramework": "angular1",
    "useSass": false,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": [
      "es",
      "en"
    ],
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "skipServer": true
  },
  "generator-jhipster-entity-audit": {
    "auditFramework": "custom"
  },
  "generator-jhipster-pages": {
    "promptValues": {
      "pageSet": "Reports",
      "pageType": "clientOnly"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `skipServer` set to `true` in your `.yo-rc.json` file, meaning no Java files will be generated.  I'm guessing you generated your project as a client only app or used the `skip-server` flag.

If you want the Java to be generated, set `skipServer` to false.  You may be missing some necessary Java files if your project was generated without a backend.